# FTP zip script - STUCK

Tags: iphone, bash, unix, terminal

I have a bash code to backup my iOS files and send them to my website FTP in the directory: (http://mywebsite.com/sms) but when I run this code, it isn't .zip'ing the files and leaves the file 'zippyy.db' in the root of my website, not in the /sms folder.

I will be running this script from a few devices so when I execute the code, if there is already a file in the FTP called zippyy.zip, it will change it to zippyy1.zip, zippyy2.zip etc..

I would be really grateful for somebody to re-write the script for me. Thank you in advance! Here's my code:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 ROOTFOLDER="/var/root"
 ZIPNAME="zipfolder"
 ZIPFOLDER=$ROOTFOLDER/$ZIPNAME
 LIBFOLDER="/var/mobile/Library"
 ZIPFILE="zippyy.zip"

 mkdir -p $ZIPFOLDER
 cp $LIBFOLDER/SMS/sms.db $ZIPFOLDER/
 cp $LIBFOLDER/Notes/notes.sqlite $ZIPFOLDER/
 cp $LIBFOLDER/Safari/Bookmarks.db $ZIPFOLDER/
 cp $LIBFOLDER/Safari/History.plist $ZIPFOLDER/
 cd $ROOTFOLDER
 zip -r $ZIPFILE $ZIPNAME

 HOST=HOSTNAME
 USER=USERNAME
 PASS=PASSWORD

 ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
 user $USER $PASS
 cd sms
 dir . remote_dir.txt
 bye
 EOF

 FILECOUNT=$(grep zippyy remote_dir.txt | wc -l)
 NEXTDB="zippyy${FILECOUNT}.db"
 mv $ZIPFILE $NEXTDB

 ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
 user $USER $PASS
 put $NEXTDB
 bye
 EOF
```

Comment: Run your script with `sh -x script`.

Comment: Almost worked! Just need to figure out why i'm getting a .db file instead of a .zip??

Comment: Maybe because of `NEXTDB="zippyy${FILECOUNT}.db"`.

Comment: Changed, thanks for that! But the only problem now is when I go to extract the .zip, I get "Archive Corrupt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean your archive is corrupt once it's been ftp'd?

Its likely your sending the file in default mode on your machine, which must be ASCII mode.

But first, on you local copy of zip file, issue the test option

```
zip -t $ZIPFILE
```

If that succeeds, then change you ftp here-doc to

```
ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
 user $USER $PASS
 binary
 put $NEXTDB
 bye
EOF
```

Note the addition of the ftp command `binary`, which means send file without translations for ASCII.

---

It's highly recommended to issue the following command

```
 man ftp
```

And read through it at least once. Granted there are sections of even a good ftp man page that I have failed to find useful! ;-) . Also be aware that there are many ftp clients, with only a semblance of adherence to a common set of options, parameters and sub-commands. Don't assume that once you get it working at home, that it will work at the office, or at your friends place!

IHTH

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you, sir! I just added the line: binary after user $USER $PASS

Thank you again :)

Comment: OH! Just one more question mate, this script requires me to login as root, how could I write sudo into the script so I don't have to use: su before running the script? Would you mind just writing the little code for me so I could just copy it in? Would be really grateful! Thank you :)

Comment: I don't have much experience with `sudo`. Are you in a work environment? If so they likely have rules against you doing such things. If you doing this from home, you have to read the `sudo` man page and find out what entries to make into the sudo config files. Good luck.

Comment: Just a script from home, thank you so much for the script and advice! :)

Comment: incidentally, since you have control over your envrionment, it's not clear why you need to run this as root. That creates a security hole that once exploited, would require a complete rebuild of your system to fix. There should be ways of doing anything related to an application data without using root. Good luck.